# Is "decomposition" of every Friedlander-Iwaniec prime unique?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

If by Friedlander-Iwaniec primes we mean primes of form $a^2 + b^4$, can we be sure that $a$ and $b$ here are always unique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$97 = 4^2 + 3^4 = 9^2 + 2^4$$

But that sort of thing is the only problem, since the representation of a prime as the sum of two squares (if it exists, i.e. $p = 2$ or $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$) is unique.

Comment: I wasn't precise in my original question, I intended to exclude this case but forgot. So this special case of sum of two squares is the only case when uniqueness is not met?

Comment: Yes. By the unique factorisation in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, the representation of $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ (or $p = 2$) as the sum of two squares is unique. Thus for Friedlander-Iwaniec primes the set $\{a, b^2\}$ is uniquely determined (assuming we look only at nonnegative $a,b$, otherwise we could take $-a$ instead of $a$). If the prime is not the sum of two fourth powers, this determines $a$ and $b$ (up to the sign) uniquely.